Заменить скролл страницы на скролл элемента

"Все по дизайну"
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы скролился лишь центральный элемент страницы (посты), а боковые элементы и шапка оставалась неподвижной. Header сделать fixed еще окей, но делать fixed или sticky боковые элементы не вариант, тк адаптив ужасно неприятно делать будет (или придется кастыльно с доп элементами).
Вопрос заключается в том, можно ли как то заменить скролл страницы на скролл центрального элемента или просто как то аккуратно сверстать все или что нибудь сделать через JS?
Проект делается на React к слову.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
